# jQuery form fields validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form with few input fields with class "inputfields" need to validate each field if empty alert 'fieldname is empty' otherwise return true my jquery code is not working keep getting errors at the console log can any one help please ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        $('.inputfields').each.on('change keyup' ,function(){
            var ope = $(this).attr('name');
            if (ope.val()==''){
                alert(ope+'is empty');
                }else {
                    console.log(ope);
                    }
                });
    });
```

Comment: What errors are shown?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function operatorprofile01.php:446
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: `.each.on`... I've never seen jQuery used like that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to check different types of input fields, hence want to use `change` and `keyup`.

I tried something based on your code, but this following solution will only work, if you want to validate text type input fields. For `select` or other input types you have to put some more checks inside the loop or have to some other way to validate.

```
    $('.inputfields').each(function() {
        $(this).bind('change keyup', function() {
            var ope = $(this).attr('name');
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                console.log(ope+'is empty');
            } else {
                console.log(ope+ ' : ' + $(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
```

Hope this will lead you to find your desired solution.

Comment: works perfectly thanks a lot, just one more thing here you add conditions if change , keyup  would like also to add if form submitted i inserted  $(this).bind('change keyup submit', function() , but it didn't work is there another way ?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I'm happy that it was helpful. I believe forms & inputs should be validated separately as they are separate type of entities. Even if you successfully bind `change` `keyup` & `submit` in one, you have to put separate checks for each. So my suggestion would be to validate those separately. Besides someone else here suggested about http://jqueryvalidation.org/, which I believe, will save you long way. Refraining from re-inventing the wheel should be the way to go. Just my two cents.